# EFCreateError with JvCsvDataSet

Tags: delphi, jedi

I have been using JvCSVDataSet with Delphi 5 and it works fine. I just moved over to Delphi 2007 and now with the same program I get EFCreateError, cannot create file "" I got the error description from MadExcept 3.0.

Here are the code,I get the error in the line 'CADDCOUNT', but if I rem out that line then I don't get the error before I close the dataset.

```
jvCsvDataSet1.FileName := 'C:\TEST.CSV';
jvCsvDataSet1.SaveToFile('C:\TEST.CSV');
jvCsvDataSet1.Active := True;
jvCsvDataSet1.Append;
jvCsvDataSet1.FieldByName('LINETYPE').Asstring := 'VERSION';
jvCsvDataSet1.FieldByName('CADDCOUNT').AsString := 'Company Name and address';
jvCsvDataSet1.Post;
jvCsvDataSet1.Active := False;
```

Thanks,
for any help.
Kim

Answer (score 1):

You didn't simply happen to change to Vista or Windows 7 too ? They don't allow you to write to the root of the startup drive.